# Iterate an function and push it into an array to create an array with a certain number of element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, push

I created a function to return a random color and apply pretty much anywhere in my document. So far so good but now I wish to create an array of a definite number (it doesn't matter how many item, but let's say four) so then I can use the value of the array to change the color of each letter of a certain word.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="colourword">Anyword</div>

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }

  var colors = getRandomColor();

  $('colourword').html(function() {
    return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
      return '<span style="color:' +colors+ '";>' + el + '</span>';
    }).join('');
  });
```

The problem is that I don't know how to iterate my function to create the array.

I really don't know where to start, I tried to push the function in an array but then I don't know how to insert a number (for example i<5).

I really need an hint or at least the principle to iterate the array.

Thanks

Comment: You want to loop a 4-colors array for an unkown number of times (could be `> 4`)?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I'd like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `%` operator to always stay in the range of the array:

```
var colors = [/*...*/]; // fill array with any number of colors you want

$('colourword').html(function() {
    return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
        return '<span style="color:' + colors[i % colors.length] + '";>' + el + '</span>';
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }).join('');
});
```

Because for any number `N` and `L`:  `0 <= N % L < L`.

**Example:**

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

var colors = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)                // fill the array with 4 random colors
  colors.push(getRandomColor());

$('.colourword').html(function() {
  return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
    return '<span style="color:' + colors[i % colors.length] + ';">' + el + '</span>';
  }).join('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colourword">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
```

Comment: This snippet doesn't work. It return something like that: <span style="color:#" ;="">W</span>

Comment: @Matto You should fill the array first: `var colors = ["#f00", ...];`. See my up-to-date answer.

Comment: I created a function here: function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }

It returns a random color. I need random colors

Comment: @Matto I've added a runnable code snippet. I understood that you want the text to be colored with 4 repeating random colors. Right? If not so then please clarify.

Comment: Your answer is probably the most complete. Is it possible to accept two answers?

Comment: No, it's actually the best one. Becuase it is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Still, can you tell me why this is return: <span style="color:#FB97C5" ;="">W</span>. The HTML and the code work fine but I don't understand it returns this markup ;="" (if you inspect the element you'll probably see it

Comment: @Matto It's because you have `+ '";>' +` where it should be `';">'`. (your code generate `style="...";` where `;` ouside of `""`, it should be `style="...;"` where `;` is inside of `""`). Notice the difference?

Comment: @Matto So the browser interpret `;` as being a separate attribute.

Comment: Seriously.. I should learn a lot of stuff from you.. thank you, you're a great coder

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close. I don't think you need to create an array, however. Just call the function within your map callback. I've used all vanilla JS in this example.

```js
var colourword = document.querySelector('.colourword');
var text = colourword.textContent;

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

colourword.innerHTML = Array.from(text).map(function(letter) {
  return '<span style="color:' + getRandomColor() + '";>' + letter + '</span>';
}).join('');
```

```html
<div class="colourword">Anyword</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need an array. You could just call getRandomColor within the mapping function:

```
$('colourword').html(function() {
    return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
        var color = getRandomColor();
        return '<span style="color: ' + color + '";>' + el + '</span>';
    }).join('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an array for solving the problem you mentioned you can just call the function inside the map call back function as follows:

```
<div class="colourword">Anyword</div>

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
  $('colourword').html(function() {
     return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
         var colors = getRandomColor(); 
         return '<span style="color:' +colors+ '">' + el + '</span>';
   }).join('');
 });
```

Comment: Perfect, it's what I'm looking for. Do you know why it is returned an element like that: <span style="color: #3AF92B" ;="">W</span> ?

I don't understand the semicolon and the equal sign with an empty element at the very end..

Comment: I edited the code. Now there will be no ;. If this is a right answer for you then why don't you accept it to help future readers

Comment: I will do it, the problem is that all of the answers are right! One more thing:

Do you have any idea about this output?

<span style="color: #3AF92B" ;="">W</span>

It appears that the return on the span element added a weird code at the very end, even if I haven't found it anywhere.. great code by the way. You all guys were awesome!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at y end